# What does "m" mean in mpstat?

Tags: command-line, cpu

I check the manual of `mpstat` it states:

> The mpstat command writes to standard output activities  for  each  available
>      processor,  processor 0 being the first one.  Global average activities among
>      all processors are also reported.  The mpstat command can be used both on SMP
>      and  UP  machines,  but in the latter, only global average activities will be
>      printed. If no activity has been selected, then the default report is the CPU
>      utilization report.

However, I didn't get the idea what does m mean in mpstat?  is it multiple?

Comment: mpstat - multiprocessing statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what the M in `mpstat` means. **NOTE:** `mpstat` is part of the sysstat package and so is part of a family of *stat tools:

```
$ rpm -ql sysstat | grep /bin/
/usr/bin/cifsiostat
/usr/bin/iostat
/usr/bin/mpstat
/usr/bin/nfsiostat-sysstat
/usr/bin/pidstat
/usr/bin/sadf
/usr/bin/sar
/usr/bin/tapestat
```

It's likely the case that the M stands for one of the following:

- multi-processor
- multiple-processors
- microprocessor
- machine
- monitor

Given the top of the [`mpstat.c`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat) source code describes it as this:

> - mpstat: per-processor statistics

I'd be inclined to go with the multiple. This seems to be consistent with the source code if you glance through it, given it goes out of its way to deal with both single (UP) and multiple CPUs (SMP).

Example comments from code:

> - Structures used to save CPU and NUMA nodes CPU stats
> - Compute CPU "all" as sum of all individual CPU (on SMP machines and look for offline CPU.
> - Read total number of interrupts received among all CPU.
> - What is the highest processor number on this machine?

**NOTE:** One thing I find curious with this tool, is that if the M is meant to represent multi*, this word never actually appears in the source code, `mpstat.c`.

#### References

- [Wikipedia - mpstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat)
- [sysstat utilities](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/)

Comment: `mpstat` is part of the `SUNWcsu` package, so it is part of the base system. You seem to talk about a clone implementation...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Linux Magazine](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2953/) it looks like "multi-processor". I'm sure "multiple processor" would work, too.

Answer (score -2):

`mpstat` is from the first multi processor enhancements from `SunOS-4.x`.

There is no hint to `multi processor` in the source code nor in the man page, so there it could only be seen as an obvious explanation.